# why my printf is always repeating the first output

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a = 16777215;
    int b = pow(2, 26);
    float c = 22345678;
    printf("%f\n", a);
    printf("%f\n", b);
    puts("---------------");
    printf("%f\n", c);
    printf("%f\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
16777215.000000
16777215.000000
---------------
22345678.000000
22345678.000000
```

why the former printf output can have influence to the subsequent printf output?

Comment: Enable warnings, `int` isn't `%f`. This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: You are invoking *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type. Determining detailed reason for this specific result will require some knowledge about the environment including calling convension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match the type or strange things can happen:

```c
printf("%d\n", b);
```

Compiling the original code with `clang` gives helpful warnings:

```
pow.c:10:20: warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    printf("%f\n", b);
            ~~     ^
            %d
pow.c:13:20: warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    printf("%f\n", b);
            ~~     ^
            %d
```

*varargs* functions like `printf` have a hard time pinning down their type requirements, it's up to compilers like `clang` to go the extra mile and show hints like this. You'll need to be extra careful when calling functions of that sort and be sure you're doing it *precisely* as documented.

As to how this ended up happening, it's not clear, but it doesn't have to be. Undefined behaviour is just that: Anything can happen. It could print the same thing. It could work. It could crash. There doesn't have to be an explanation.

Comment: Or `printf("%f\n", (double)b);`

Comment: Sure, but the path of least resistance is a one letter fix.

Answer (score 0):

b isn't a float. Try %i for integer or %d for decimal.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>
 
 int main(void)
 {
     float a = 16777215;
     int b = pow(2, 26);
     float c = 22345678;
     printf("%f\n", a);
     printf("%i\n", b);
     puts("---------------");
     printf("%f\n", c);
     printf("%i\n", b);
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behavior as you try to print integer with %f

Try

```
printf("%d\n", b);
```

To answer your specific question, my guess is that, at the assembly level, if the conversion is not correctly indicated, it will jump to ret, using the value previously stored in eax register.